# Bhattacharya Distance Bug in R Function

Tags: r, distance, distribution, normal-distribution

While using the bhattacharya.dist() function available in library("fps") we run into a bug that gives -Inf when calculating this distance for two distributions which are the same. (The correct value is zero in this case). 
This happens because of multiplication of two large values in the function. I have posted the old code and the code with the fix below.

Could some experts please verify if this is correct and also suggest how this fix can be brought to the attention of the owners of this library and distributed out etc. Please note, I am very new to R and statistics etc. Hence I am concerned there might be some issues with this fix.

I have run some tests with matrices of different sizes and see expected results. But admittedly, (due to my lack of software development skills) it is nowhere close to a thorough test.

## OLD ROUTINE

> bhattacharyya.dist

```
function (mu1, mu2, Sigma1, Sigma2) 
{
    aggregatesigma <- (Sigma1 + Sigma2)/2
    d1 <- mahalanobis(mu1, mu2, aggregatesigma)/8
    d2 <- log(det(as.matrix(aggregatesigma))/sqrt(det(as.matrix(Sigma1)) * 
        det(as.matrix(Sigma2))))/2
    out <- d1 + d2
    out
}
```

## NEW ROUTINE WITH BUG FIX

```
bhattacharyyaDistance = function (mu1, mu2, Sigma1, Sigma2) 
{
  aggregatesigma <- (Sigma1 + Sigma2)/2;
  d1 <- mahalanobis(mu1, mu2, aggregatesigma)/8;
  #d2 <- log(det(as.matrix(aggregatesigma))/sqrt(det(as.matrix(Sigma1)) * 
  #                                                det(as.matrix(Sigma2))))/2;
  d2 <- log((det(as.matrix(aggregatesigma))/sqrt(det(as.matrix(Sigma1)))) 
                                            / sqrt(det(as.matrix(Sigma2))))/2;

  out <- d1 + d2;
  return(out);
};
```

Comment: I haven't used that library and am unfamiliar with that function, so I cannot give you advice on your fix, but R has a standard way to report bugs.  See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/bug.report.html) for information.  Using `bug.report(package="fps")` along with other relevant parameters should direct you to where you can report it.

Comment: @Matthew … Thanks I will report the bug ...